# Javascript replace with $1 as var

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following situation:
There is a certain string that contains some vars, such as:

```
var string = '/page/{id}/{title}';
```

Now, I want to be able to replace {id} and {title} with the vars from the following array:

```
var arr = {'id':10, 'title':'test-page'};
```

I came up with this little regex:

```
string.replace ( /{([a-zA-Z0-9]+)}/g , '$1' );
```

Which, as expected, just returns this:

```
/page/id/title
```

So I tried this:

```
string.replace ( /{([a-zA-Z0-9]+)}/g , arr [ '$1' ] );
```

But that returns a

```
/page/undefined/undefined
```

Now, I understand that something like this would be possible with a loop et cetera, but it would be nice to have a one-liner for this. I am not very used to JS, so I hope that there is some function or option that I am unaware of that helps me out with this :).

Best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var arr = {'id':10, 'title':'test-page'};

'/page/{id}/{title}'.replace(/\{([\w\d]+?)\}/g, function(a, b) {
    return arr[b] || '';
});
```

If you use this replace thing often I would create a `String` helper prototype method. For example:

```
String.prototype.template = function(data) {
    return this.replace(/\{([\w\d]+?)\}/g, function(a, b) {
        return data[b] || '';
    });
};
```

and use it like this:

```
'/page/{id}/{title}'.template(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, now I can go back to work :)!
Your edit is indeed an even nicer solution.

Comment: Might want to handle the case of the `{tag}` isn't present in the passed in object a little more gracefully than this will do now.

Comment: @jfriend00 Like what for example. To my taste if the `{tag}` is not present it's optimal to just strip it completely. Angular does it, handelbars.

Comment: @dfsq - stripping would be fine.  What you do now ends up inserting "undefined" if the tag is not in the object.

Comment: Oh you mean the first example! Yes, you are right, I was looking at prototype code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter),

> Because we want to further
>   transform the result of the match before the final substitution is
>   made, we must use a function. This forces the evaluation of the match
>   prior to the `toLowerCase()` method. If we had tried to do this using
>   the match without a function, the `toLowerCase()` would have no effect.

(In the text above, replace `toLowerCase()` with "accessing property in object")

Then, you can use

```
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3/*, ...*/, offset, string){
    return arr[p1];
}
var arr = {'id':10, 'title':'test-page'};
'/page/{id}/{title}'.replace(/\{([\w\d]+?)\}/g, replacer);
```